# Best practise for partial including git repository?

Tags: git, version-control

I would like to include the *src* folder of git repository 1 into a subfolder of repository 2.

The Why:

- Following the Sencha Touch conventions, [repository 1](https://github.com/Bancha/BanchaScaffold)'s src folder should be at *webroot/js/scaffold* in [repository 2](https://github.com/Bancha/Bancha)
- I don't want to include the files manually, since all test cases and all further development will stay in [repository 1](https://github.com/Bancha/BanchaScaffold)

Is there an elegant way for this?

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of recording the exact version of `repo1` you will be using at any time in `repo2`, I would still consider [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

But, since you only want one directory (`src`) or `repo1`, named differently (`scaffold`), in an *existing* directory (`js`) of `repo2`, I would:

- add `repo1` as a submodule in `repo2` (anywhere you want)
- make a symlink between `repo2/webroot/js/scaffold` and `repo1/src`

Comment: symlink might make problems in some environments. So, if possible I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: @RolandSchütz which ones? Even Windows now has symlink :) I use them all the time: here is one in my project: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitlab/cnf. That means, you can version that symlink.

Comment: Ok, short update. I couldn't get it running because CakePHP does not follow symbolic links. I not configured my frontend to load these classes from a different path